# how to read the maven plugin properties inside code

Tags: maven, gauge

I am using gauge maven plugin to execute my tests with the following command.

```
mvn clean install gauge:execute -DspecsDir=specs/ -Denv=android -DinParallel=true
```

I want to read the argument **inParallel** inside my code to make some decision. How can I read a plugin property inside code. I tried to google and read the documentation but couldn't find any. May be I am not using right keyword. Can someone help me understand how do I read the argument. Also I would appreciate if you could direct me a site/ forum where I can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the Maven project

```java
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", readonly = true)
private MavenProject project;
```

and then call in your code:

```java
Properties properties = project.getProperties();
```